# Is there a word for the round-trip time of a train line?

Tags: single-word-requests

On a subway line, trains go from the starting terminus to the other terminus, and then back to the starting terminus.  Is there a word that is usually used to refer to the time it takes for a train to travel as described?

"Round-trip time" seems to be mainly used when referring to packets on the Internet.

This is the context in which I want to use this word:  "The blue line has a shorter _______ than the green line, so fewer trains are required."

EDIT: I would like to specifically refer to the *time* taken, not the *distance* covered (since the *time* taken could depend on lots of other things, like the waiting time at each station and the speed at which trains travel).  For example, the word "headway" specifically refers to the *time* interval between consecutive trains, instead of the *distance* between them.  (The distance between them changes as they travel on the subway line, but the headway never changes (assuming an ideal situation where each station has a fixed duration for which every train must wait, and each track has a fixed speed at which every train must travel).)  I am hoping that there is a similar train-specific term for the duration that I am describing.

Comment: *Round trip* is what it's called. You can buy *one-way tickets* or *round-trip tickets*. And you can ask how how long each type of trip takes.

Comment: @JasonBassford "Round trip" seems to usually refer to a commuter's trip (which does not necessarily reach the terminus), instead of the train's trip?  But I would like a word that specifically refers to the _time_, rather than the path or distance.

Comment: What about just *the blue line is shorter than the green*?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear if question is for

- linear track e.g. `A-> B -> C -> B -> A` or
- a ring track e.g. `A -> B -> C -> D -> A`.

For a ring track consider *circuit*:

> The blue line has a shorter **circuit** than the green line, so fewer trains are required.

... or perhaps for a either ring or line a  **shorter (or faster) route** works.

If your prefer to focus on *time* not distance and track is a a ring then **lap time** may work:

> The blue line has a shorter **lap time** than the green line, so fewer trains are required.

Or if there is variance, you could say **average lap time**.

Comment: +1  for ***circuit*** and *circuit time*.  Not sure I like lap time for this though.

Comment: The word "route" seems acceptable somewhat, but doesn't it still refer somewhat to the path/distance, rather than the time?  It doesn't seem to give the same focus on time like the word "headway", which is specially used to describe the _time_ interval between trains.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a ***cycle***.

> "The blue line has a shorter ***cycle*** than the green line, so fewer
>   trains are required."

MW:

> **[cycle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cycle)**
>
> *noun*
>
> **2a**: a course or series of events or operations that recur regularly and usually lead back to the starting point

Answer (score 0):

A word often used in this (and broader) sense is ***turnaround*** (also *turnaround time*).

> "The blue line has a shorter (quicker) ***turnaround*** than the green
>   line, so fewer trains are required."

Collins:

> **[turnaround](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turnaround)**
>
> *noun*
>
> 2.
>
> the total time taken by a ship, aircraft, or other vehicle in a round
>   trip
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Comment: I have seen "turnaround time" (referring to intercity and commuter trains) used only to mean the time spent preparing a train for its next trip (cleaning, restocking, sometimes actually turning the train to face the other direction). This meaning might be confused with "turnaround time" if that phrase is used to mean a round trip without any servicing of the train. Or maybe not.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the notion of **period** or **frequency** here.

> The blue line has a shorter ***period*** than the green line, so fewer trains are required.
>
> The blue line *returns more **frequently*** than the green line, so fewer trains are required.